# perl DBIx::Tree::NestedSet: fails while using different column names

Tags: perl

I'm using the perl module DBIx::Tree::NestedSet for nested data set. When i use the default table name it works fine. Whereas when i want to read the table with different column name it fails.

```
my $tree = DBIx::Tree::NestedSet->new(
table_name=>$tree_table,
left_column_name=>'leftt',
right_column_name=>'rightt',                                    
dbh=>$dbh,
db_type=>$db_type
);

my $childrens = $tree->get_self_and_children_flat(id=>$root_id,depth=>1);
print "childrens: @$childrens\n"; #empty array....
```

Comment: logs? DBIC_TRACE output?